# Can you help me solve the problem in my code?

Tags: c

I am having a hard time figuring out what's wrong in my code. After inputting, for example, 2000 02 10, the output must be "Aquarius: (and any phrase in the text file)". However, after running the code, the output is just

```
Invalid month
Invalid month
Invalid day
Invalid month
Invalid day
```

Can you help me please? Here is the instruction given to us.

> The file data.for contains 60 lines. Every 12 lines represents a
> fortune for one of the 12 signs.

> Additionally, write the date inputs of the user to a file called
> data.in. One line per entry.

> data.in should have the following format: YYYY-mm-dd.

And here is the code I've made:

```
#include <stdio.h>    
#include <string.h>

#define m_size 12
#define max_line 200

int leapnt(int y);
void grab_f(int cons_num, char* receive, int* mem);
char* conste_grab(int cons);
char* zodiac(int y, int m, int d);
void memory_up(int cons_num, int* mem_arr);
int trans_cons_int(char* conste);
void read_mem(int* mem_arr);
void save(int year, int month, int day);

int main(){
    int d,m,y;
    int mem[m_size];
    for(int i=0;i<m_size;i++){mem[i]=0;}
    int cons_num;

    char* conste;
    char fortune[160];

    read_mem(mem);

    scanf("%d %02d %02d",&y, &m, &d);

    conste = zodiac(y,m,d);
    cons_num = trans_cons_int(conste);
    grab_f(cons_num, fortune, mem);

    printf("%s: %s", conste, fortune);
    save(y,m,d);
    
    return 0;
}

int leapnt(int y){
    return(((y%4)==0)&&((y%100)!=0)||((y%400)==0));
}

void grab_f(int cons_num, char* receive, int* mem){
    char *error = "File opening error";
    char fortune[max_line];
    char buff[max_line];
    int multiplier;
    multiplier = cons_num+(12 * mem[cons_num]);

    FILE* fp = fopen("data.for", "r");
    if(fp == NULL){
        printf("\nerror!\n\n");return;
    }
    for(int i=0; i<multiplier;i++){
        fscanf(fp, "%*[^\n]\n", buff);
    }
    fscanf(fp, "%[^\n]", fortune);
    strcpy(receive, fortune);
    fclose(fp);
}

char* conste_grab(int cons){
    char* starsn[] = {"Aquarius","Pisces","Aries","Taurus","Gemini", "Cancer","Leo","Virgo","Libra","Scorpio", "Saggitarius","Capricorn"};
    return starsn[cons-1];
}

char* zodiac(int y, int m, int d){
    char* error = "constellation error";
    int max[12] = {31,(leapnt(y)?29:28),31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31};
    if(d < 1 || d > max[m-1]){
        printf("\nInvalid day"); return error; 
    }
    if(m < 1 || m > 12){
        printf("\nInvalid month"); 
        return error; 
    }
    char* conste;

    switch(m){
        case 1:
            if(d > 19 && d < max[m-1]){
                conste = conste_grab(m);
            }
            else{
                conste = conste_grab(12);
            }
            break;

        case 2:
            if(d > 18 && d < max[m-1]){  
                conste = conste_grab(m); 
            }
            else{  
                conste = conste_grab(m-1);
            }
            break;

        case 3:
            if(d > 20 && d < max[m-1]){  
                conste = conste_grab(m); 
            }
            else{  
                conste = conste_grab(m-1);
            }
                break;

        case 4:
            if(d > 19 && d < max[m-1]){  
                conste = conste_grab(m); 
            }
            else{  
                conste = conste_grab(m-1);
            }
            break;

        case 5:
            if(d > 20 && d < max[m-1]){  
                conste = conste_grab(m); 
            }
            else{  
                conste = conste_grab(m-1);
            }
            break;

        case 6:
            if(d > 21 && d < max[m-1]){  
                conste = conste_grab(m); 
            }
            else{  
                conste = conste_grab(m-1);
            }
            break;

        case 7:
            if(d > 22 && d < max[m-1]){  
                conste = conste_grab(m); 
            }
            else{  
                conste = conste_grab(m-1);
            }
            break;

        case 8:
            if(d > 22 && d < max[m-1]){  
                conste = conste_grab(m); 
            }
            else{
                conste = conste_grab(m-1);
            }
            break;

        case 9:
            if(d > 22 && d < max[m-1]){
                conste = conste_grab(m);
            }
            else{
                conste = conste_grab(m-1);
            }
            break;

        case 10:
            if(d > 23 && d < max[m-1]){  
                conste = conste_grab(m); 
            }
            else{  
                conste = conste_grab(m-1);
            }
            break;

        case 11:
            if(d > 21 && d < max[m-1]){  
                conste = conste_grab(m); 
            }
            else{  
                conste = conste_grab(m-1);
            }
            break;

        case 12:
            if(d > 21 && d < max[m-1]){  
                conste = conste_grab(m); 
            }
            else{  
                conste = conste_grab(m-1);
            }
            break;

        default: return error;
    }
    return conste;
}

void memory_up(int cons_num, int* mem_arr){
    mem_arr[cons_num]++;
}

int trans_cons_int(char* conste){
    int cons_num;
    char* starsn[] = {"Aquarius","Pisces","Aries","Taurus","Gemini", "Cancer","Leo","Virgo","Libra","Scorpio", "Saggitarius","Capricorn"};

    for(int i=0; i<m_size; i++){
        if(strcmp(starsn[i], conste)==0){
            cons_num=i;
            return cons_num;
        }
    }
}

void read_mem(int* mem_arr){
    int year, month, day;
    char* conste;
    int cons_num;

    FILE* fp = fopen("data.in", "r");
    if(fp == NULL){
        printf("\n\tfopen error!\n");
    }
    while(fscanf(fp,"%d-%d-%d", &year, &month, &day) != EOF){
        conste = zodiac(year,month,day);
        cons_num = trans_cons_int(conste);
        memory_up(cons_num, mem_arr);
    }
    fclose(fp);
}

void save(int year, int month, int day){
    FILE* fp = fopen("data.in", "ab");
    if(!fp){
        printf("\n\tFile open error\n");
        return;
    }
    fprintf(fp,"%d-%02d-%02d",year,month,day);
    fprintf(fp,"\n");
    fclose(fp);
}
```

Comment: Why are you reading from `data.in`? The instructions say you're supposed to write the input values there, not read from it.

Comment: Turn up your warnings. Like to pedantic levels, and treat them as errors (because that's what they are).

Comment: You are taking input from `data.in` before taking input from the console. More dangerously, You are still taking input from `data.in` in `read_mem()` even if the file does not exist! Why man?

Comment: If your code behaves unexpectedly, then, as a rule, you should verify your code catches all IO errors. Does it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried out your code and when I figured out I also needed to create a file known as "data.in" I was able to run your code.  I could not replicate the issue when entering the year, month, and day you tried.  But, having a look at your code, I would suggest a small tweak to the place where you scan in user input.  Usually, it is helpful to provide textual information as a prompt prior to requesting the user to input a value.  With that in mind, here is the revision to your "scanf" block of code.

```
    //scanf("%d %02d %02d",&y, &m, &d);
    printf("Please enter year of birth: ");
    scanf("%d", &y);
    printf("Please enter month of birth: ");
    scanf("%02d", &m);
    printf("Please enter day of birth: ");
    scanf("%02d", &d);
```

When I ran the program with those revisions, here is what I saw on my terminal.

```
Please enter year of birth: 1955
Please enter month of birth: 11
Please enter day of birth: 4
Scorpio: Today is your lucky day
```

And here is the data that went into file "data.in".

```
1955-11-04
```

You might try out the "printf/scanf" combo and see if you still get an issue.

Regards.

Answer (score -1):

Everyone who is reading this is having a hard time finding out what is wrong with your code too.

Here is why -- you have not taken a modular approach to solving this problem.

Let me explain.  First we need to step back an see what is needed to solve this problem

1. A way to read in the user input, parse it and understand what date and what sign that input represents
2. A way to (given that sign) read a fortune from the data file
3. A way to write out what fortune we sent to the user
4. A way to make sure that we don't give the same fortune twice

This list gives you a sense of parts of this program and also a plan to solve it.  Solve the first first step first and make sure it is working.  Then move on to the next step.

> I built this list from experience so I know what steps to do first --- as you gain more programming experience knowing what modules to write first and what to have in them will become clear.

In your code I see as the 2nd line code that is trying to do step 4 while at the same time is clear (from the error messages) that you never solved step 1.

Start a new program and solve step 1.  Then add in in step order each of the next steps.  It might seem now like that is going backwards but I can assure you if you don't you will never be able to finish.